# Using String.Contains on a Null value string

Tags: c#, string

In my application I am getting the description filed from Active Directory and then assigning it to a string so I can later check that string for "Contracted" in order to ignore that users.
The problem is not all users have a value in the description field which results in a `Null Reference Exception` being thrown. The only way I can think of dealing with this is to add another check using `String.IsNullOrEmpty` and add a temp value, then later remove that temp value. This seems cumbersome and wrong.

What do I need to do to deal with `null` in the string during my check? I have tried the following two sets of code, both throw the error:

```
var userDescription = (string)userDirectoryData.Properties["description"].Value;

if (userDescription.Contains("Contracted"))
{
    continue;
}
else
{
    //Do Stuff here
}
```

And

```
var userDescription = (string)userDirectoryData.Properties["description"].Value;

if (userDescription.IndexOf("Contracted") > -1)
{
    continue;
}
else
{
    //Do Stuff here
}
```

EDIT:
According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx I can't set to String.Empty as that will return a result of "0" causing a false positive the description only contains "Contracted".

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "add a temp value", but using `String.IsNullOrEmpty` (or `String.IsNullOrWhitespace`) would be perfectly normal here.

Comment: And what is the difference between these two given snippets?

Comment: `if (userDescription != null && userDescription.IndexOf("Contracted") > -1)`

Comment: @JamesThorpe I mean added an extra `if` check to see if the desctipion is null, if it is then assign something like "temp" to the description so it can pass the check, then remove that value after the check passes.

Comment: @un-lucky Sorry, copied and pasted the wrong code snippet for the second one. Corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign an empty string if the value is null using the c# ***nullable coalesce***:

```
var userDescription = (string)userDirectoryData.Properties["description"].Value ?? String.Empty;

if (userDescription.Contains("Contracted"))
{
    continue;
}
else
{
    //Do Stuff here
}
```

Comment: IndexOf will return 0 on a String.Empty value though meaning that the check would flag false positives  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx

Comment: Yep, though your post remained me I could do it with the`.Contains` but of coarse when I forget a little point I get a hate storm but when an answer does no one hates on it. Really pushes people away from SO.

Answer (score 3):

A bit combersome C# 6.0 syntax `?.` (instead of `.` in `userDescription.Contains`) can be used

```
  if (userDescription?.Contains("Contracted") == true) {
    continue;
  }
  else {
    // Do Stuff here
  }
```

unfortunatelly (in this particular case) `Boolean?` can't be cast *implicitly* to `Boolean` and that's why `== true` should be added. In case of `IndexOf` the  code looks quite OK:

```
  if (userDescription?.IndexOf("Contracted") > -1) {
    continue;
  }
  else {
    // Do Stuff here
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could override `Contains()` and `IndexOf` and define a custom output in case the string is null like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool Contains(this string value, string search)
    {
        if(value != null)
        {
            return value.Contains(search);

        }
        else
        {
            // IF ITS NULL DEFINE YOUR RETURN HERE
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static int IndexOf(this string value, string search)
    {
        if(value != null)
        {
            return value.IndexOf(search);
        }
        else
        {
            // IF ITS NULL DEFINE YOUR RETURN HERE
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The usage stays the same except from the behaviour with null-values. Check my comments.

Comment: Bit overkill don't you think?

Comment: I wish this had worked, but it does not override the original "Contains" method from the String class. I can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Before C# 6 using `string.IsNullOrEmpty` (or James Dev's answer) is necessary

```
var userDescription = (string)userDirectoryData.Properties["description"].Value;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userDescription) && userDescription.IndexOf("Contracted") > -1)
{
    continue;
}
else
{
    //Do Stuff here
}
```

With C# 6 you could reduce this to the null propagation operator (`?.`):

```
if ((string)userDirectoryData.Properties["description"].Value?.IndexOf("Contracted") > -1)
{
    continue;
}
else
{
    //Do Stuff here
}
```